# Building libreoffice gives an error and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: android, makefile, build, libreoffice

Build output is:

```
... very long output of compiled files is omitted...

[MAK] CustomTarget/android/source/done
creating liboSettings.gradle
[build PY ] native-code.cxx
/bin/sh: 1: /home/bart/Projects/libreoffice/solenv/bin/native-code.py: not found
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'native-code.cxx' failed
make[2]: *** [native-code.cxx] Error 127
/home/bart/Projects/libreoffice/android/CustomTarget_lo_android.mk:17: recipe for target '/home/bart/Projects/libreoffice/workdir/CustomTarget/android/source/done' failed
make[1]: *** [/home/bart/Projects/libreoffice/workdir/CustomTarget/android/source/done] Error 2
Makefile:282: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

My *autogen.input* is:

```
--with-distro=LibreOfficeAndroid
--with-android-sdk=/home/bart/Android/Sdk
--with-android-ndk=/home/bart/Android/android-ndk-r20
--with-jdk-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

I have used [this page](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/BuildingForAndroid) as a manual.

Also, I have noticed that native-code.cxx file is empty in libreoffice/android/source

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out. I didn't had python2 installed on my system (however had python3). Could **configure** check it?